# Kafka SASL/PLAIN Setup with SSL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to configure SASL/PLAIN with SSL in our Kafka environment. The SSL part is done, but I'm running into the below error when starting the Zookeeper.
Has anyone configured SASL/PLAIN with SSL for Zookeeper and broker ?

**Server-Broker Config**

```
broker.id=19
port=19001

#host.name=localhost
host.name=jcia9081

#advertised.host.name=11.72.29.153

num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8

socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

log.dirs=/appsdata/osp/kafka/datastore1/AIN_TEST_SSL/kafka,/appsdata/osp/kafka/datastore2/AIN_TEST_SSL/kafka,/appsdata/osp/kafka/datastore3/AIN_TEST_SSL/kafka

num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

log.retention.hours=96
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

log.cleaner.enable=false

replica.fetch.max.bytes=52428800

#The maximum size of a message that the server can receive.
message.max.bytes=52428800

zookeeper.connect=jcia9081:19101,jcia9131:19101,jcia9434:19101
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
#################################
auto.create.topics.enable=false
auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true
delete.topic.enable=true
controlled.shutdown.enable=true

### SSL properties
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
listeners=SSL://jcia9081:19001,SASL_SSL://jcia9081:19002
ssl.keystore.location=/home/kafka/certs/jcia9081.federated.fds.jks
ssl.keystore.password=xxxx
ssl.key.password=xxxx
ssl.truststore.location=/home/kafka/certs/test.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=xxx
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
#listeners=SSL://jcia9081:19001
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
```

**Zookeeper Config**

```
dataDir=/appsdata/osp/kafka/datastore1/AIN_TEST_SSL/zookeeper

clientPort=19101

maxClientCnxns=0

tickTime=2000

initLimit=60
syncLimit=10

server.19=jcia9081:19121:19131
server.20=jcia9131:19121:19131
server.21=jcia9434:19121:19131
```

**JAAS Zookeeper Configuration File**

```
Server {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret"
   user_admin="admin-secret"
};
```

**JAAS Broker Configuration File**

```
    KafkaServer {
        org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
        username="admin"
        password="admin-secret"
        user_admin="admin-secret";
        };
Client {
        org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
        username="admin"
        password="admin-secret";
};
```

**Startup Error**

```
[2017-04-26 10:05:24,775] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/appsdata/osp/kafka/AIN_TEST_SSL/startup (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-04-26 10:05:24,776] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=jcia9081:19101 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@43195e57 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-04-26 10:05:24,776] INFO Starting ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2017-04-26 10:05:24,778] DEBUG zookeeper.disableAutoWatchReset is false (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-04-26 10:05:24,789] DEBUG JAAS loginContext is: Client (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2017-04-26 10:05:24,795] DEBUG Awaiting connection to Zookeeper server (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-26 10:05:24,795] INFO Waiting for keeper state SaslAuthenticated (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-26 10:05:24,881] INFO successfully logged in. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2017-04-26 10:05:24,881] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2017-04-26 10:05:24,895] INFO Opening socket connection to server jcia9081.federated.fds/11.168.24.82:19101. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-04-26 10:05:24,968] INFO Socket connection established to jcia9081.federated.fds/11.168.24.82:19101, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-04-26 10:05:24,970] DEBUG Session establishment request sent on jcia9081.federated.fds/11.168.24.82:19101 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,001] INFO Session establishment complete on server jcia9081.federated.fds/11.168.24.82:19101, sessionid = 0x15baa8300580003, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,002] DEBUG ClientCnxn:sendSaslPacket:length=0 (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,004] DEBUG Received event: WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,004] INFO zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,004] DEBUG Leaving process event (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,006] ERROR SASL authentication failed using login context 'Client'. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,006] DEBUG Received event: WatchedEvent state:AuthFailed type:None path:null (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,006] INFO zookeeper state changed (AuthFailed) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,006] DEBUG Leaving process event (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,006] DEBUG Closing ZkClient... (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,006] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,006] DEBUG Closing ZooKeeper connected to jcia9081:19101 (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,006] DEBUG Close called on already closed client (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,006] DEBUG Closing ZkClient...done (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,007] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkAuthFailedException: Authentication failure
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.waitForKeeperState(ZkClient.java:946)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.waitUntilConnected(ZkClient.java:923)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1230)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:156)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:130)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:76)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:58)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZk(KafkaServer.scala:327)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:200)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:39)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2017-04-26 10:05:25,009] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

**Broker Start Command**

```
    . /appsdata/osp/kafka/AIN_TEST_SSL/startup/setenv.sh
export JMX_PORT=19011
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_CONFIG/server_AIN_TEST_SSL.properties > $LOG_DIR/kafka-broker-startup.log 2>&1 &
```

**setenv**

```
    export APP_HOME=/apps/osp

export JAVA_HOME=$APP_HOME/jdk1.8.0_101
export JAVA=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java

export KAFKA_HOME=$APP_HOME/kafka/v2.11-0.10.1.1
export KAFKA_CONFIG=/appsdata/osp/kafka/AIN_TEST_SSL/config

export ZK_HOME=$KAFKA_HOME
export ZK_CONFIG=$KAFKA_CONFIG

export LOG_DIR=/applogs/osp/kafka/AIN_TEST_SSL
export KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:$KAFKA_CONFIG/log4j.properties"
```

**In Termninal 1**

```
echo $KAFKA_OPTS
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/appsdata/osp/kafka/AIN_TEST_SSL/config/jaas_AIN_TEST_SSL_zookeeper.conf
```

**In Terminal 2**

```
echo $KAFKA_OPTS
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/appsdata/osp/kafka/AIN_TEST_SSL/config/jaas_AIN_TEST_SSL_server.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

You should give the path to your jaas file by exporting KAFKA_OPTS environment variable. Copy your jaas file under `/appsdata/osp/kafka/AIN_TEST_SSL/config/`

I assume, this is the content of your file:

**kafka_server_jaas.conf**

```
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret"
   user_admin="admin-secret";
};
Client {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret";
};
```

**zookeeper.properties**

```
dataDir=/appsdata/osp/kafka/datastore1/AIN_TEST_SSL/zookeeper
clientPort=19101
maxClientCnxns=0
tickTime=2000
initLimit=60
syncLimit=10
server.19=jcia9081:19121:19131
server.20=jcia9131:19121:19131
server.21=jcia9434:19121:19131

#New configuration
authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
jaasLoginRenew=3600000
```

**[BEGIN UPDATE]**

Add the the zookeeper server jaas file and import it before starting zookeeper ensemble.

```
Server {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret"
   user_admin="admin-secret"
};
```

After, export that jaas on the zookeeper terminal and start zookeeper

```
$ export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/appsdata/osp/kafka/AIN_TEST_SSL/config/zookeeper_jaas.conf"
$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Open a new terminal and hit the following commands to start your kafka server:

```
$ export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/appsdata/osp/kafka/AIN_TEST_SSL/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

**[END UPDATE]**

I think it will fix your issue.

Please look at my configurations on this post if any issue occurs:

[Kafka SASL zookeeper authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469962/kafka-sasl-zookeeper-authentication)

Comment: I still get the same error when I do "export KAFKA_OPTS" and start Zookeeper.I guess something else is off.

Comment: Broker is not up. I'm trying to start the Zookeeper first.

Comment: Ok sorry for the question I was far away and forgot kafka basics. So basically after exporting the jaas file you still have the same issue? You exported the zookeeper jaas in a terminal, and in the same one you tried to start kafka, right?

Comment: I first exported the JAAS file, and then in the same terminal, I started Zookeeper.  Zookeeper never starts and dies with the error "ERROR No JAAS configuration section named 'Server' was foundin  '/appsdata/osp/kafka/AIN_TEST_SSL/config/jaas_AIN_TEST_SSL_zookeeper.conf'"

Comment: security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
listeners=SSL://jcia9082:19001,SASL_SSL://jcia9082:19002
ssl.keystore.location=/home/kafka/certs/jcia9081.federated.fds.jks
ssl.keystore.password=xxx
ssl.key.password=xxx
ssl.truststore.location=/home/kafka/certs/test.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=welcome1
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN

Comment: Ok, please edit your post by adding your configuration files. both kafka server config file and zoo.cfg

Comment: Added broker and zookeeper configuration

Comment: I updated my post. Basically, don't use a separate jaas file for zookeeper secured connection. And also, you should use `Client` instead of `Server` in jaas config file for Zookeeper. `Client` is used to authenticate zookeeper.

Comment: You are right when you say don't use separate JAAS file for zookeeper secured connection. I removed it. And I followed your instructions by configuring a JAAS file for broker only. I updated the post with the new startup error. Thank you for all the help so far.

Comment: OK, the new error is when you try to start zookeeper?

Comment: Zookeeper starts without error. Its the Broker which gives the error.

Comment: I think I know the issue. You have a syntax error on your jaas file. Look at what I just updated. I added ";" at the end of `password="admin-secret"`

Comment: Actually its a "Authentication failure "error. I updated the post. Is something missing in my broker config ?

Comment: What is the full command do you use when starting the broker?

Comment: Also please bring back your configuration files. Maybe something is missing. Probably in `zookeeper.properties` file. Please update the post by adding the content of that config

Comment: As you enable authentication via SASL, you need to set the authentication provider, require sasl authentication and configure the login renewal period in `zookeeper.properties`. I just updated my post with the new `zookeeper.properties` file. update your config and restart zookeeper, then restart kafka

Comment: I think we are making progress. After I updated the zookeeper config, I started Zookeeper and then Broker. Zookeeper starts without error, but  I'm still running into a "Authentication failure" during Broker startup. Updated post with error.

Comment: Do you use a zookeeper cluster?

Comment: Yes. A 3 node cluster running on 3 VMs  where one instance of zookeeper and broker are running on each VM .  I've updated the Zookeeper config on all 3 nodes/VMs. But I'm starting Broker only on one VM.

Comment: And do you export the jaas on the two other nodes?

Comment: yep.. I did. And when I try to start Broker on a different node, I get the same error.

Comment: Please change the log level to `DEBUG` on your kafka log4j file and re-run the kafka server, then put the new stack trace.

Comment: Also, I think you should try to re-generate keytabs

Comment: I've enabled DEBUG mode in the log4j file and updated the error output.

Comment: Ok I just updated the jaas file. I think the authentocation failed due to one line. Look at what I just added `user_admin="admin-secret"` in `KafkaServer` config. Try that and let me know please. Did you also re-generate certificates?

Comment: I updated the JAAS config file. While I did not get a authentication failure, I got a configuration error. I updated the post with the new error. No I did not regenerate the certificates. That is done by a different team and it usually takes time. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Ok no worries about the certificates. To fix the config error you need to remove the ";" at this line `password="admin-secret";` and only that. But the ";" at the bottom need to stay of course. Look deeply at what I added

Comment: After making the update, I got a "Unable to open socket" error. I've update the post with the error and new JAAS server config

Comment: Your zookeeper ensemble seems not working correctly. Please make sure zookeeper cluster nodes can communicate with each other and the ensemble is up and running

Comment: @M.Situation , any luck on solving the configuration issue, as i am facing the same Authentication Failure while trying to start kafka and my zookeeper is starting properly

Comment: You better have to ask to @AtulyaB, I don't know if it works for him. But everything should be already good. Also, do you use SSL as well? Maybe you should post your configuration by starting a new thread. Just notify me and I'll see how I can help you

Comment: @AtulyaB, Please let me know if the problem was solved for you.

Comment: @M.Situation, i have started a new thread :-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469962/kafka-sasl-zookeeper-authentication

Comment: @AtulyaB, please look at what I added on my post. It should be the solution to your issue.

Comment: @M.Situation Thank you for following up on the issue. Let me update my configuration with what you've added and I'll give you an update.

Comment: I made changes to the Zookeeper JAAS file, and I'm getting the same zookeeper startup error I got before. I updated the post with the Zookeeper startup error and zookeeper JAAS file.

Comment: Please try to setup environment variables before starting each technology. For instance, export zookeeper jaas before starting zookeeper in a terminal. In another terminal, export kafka jaas before starting kafka. I think it's looking for the Server entry in the bad file because of your env variables

Comment: I first exported the KAFKA_OPTS in terminal 1 for Zookeeper. This resolved the Zookeeper error. 
But when the export KAFKA_OPTS in terminal 2 for Kafka Broker, and start the process, I get an authentication failure.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I  username matches to the both the zookeeper and broker JAAS file. I updated my post. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Also, I think I'm going to try the SASL setup without SSL and see if it works

Comment: Ok do that first please, you can refer to @sunder post for that purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469962/kafka-sasl-zookeeper-authentication

Comment: @M.Situation I did the SASL first and then integrated that SSL and it worked. Thank you for all the help. The next step for me is to configure SSL and SASL producers and consumers and establish connectivity and data flow.

Comment: Ok you are welcome. If it answers your question please feel free to mark it as the answer!