# Kafka SASL zookeeper authentication

Tags: authentication, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, sasl

I am facing the following error while enabling SASL on Zookeeper and broker authentication.

```
[2017-04-18 15:54:10,476] DEBUG Size of client SASL token: 0 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-04-18 15:54:10,476] ERROR cnxn.saslServer is null: cnxn object did not initialize its saslServer properly. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.    ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-04-18 15:54:10,478] ERROR SASL authentication failed using login context 'Client'. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2017-04-18 15:54:10,478] DEBUG Received event: WatchedEvent state:AuthFailed type:None path:null (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-18 15:54:10,478] INFO zookeeper state changed (AuthFailed) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-18 15:54:10,478] DEBUG Leaving process event (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-18 15:54:10,478] DEBUG Closing ZkClient... (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-18 15:54:10,478] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2017-04-18 15:54:10,478] DEBUG Closing ZooKeeper connected to localhost:2181 (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection)
[2017-04-18 15:54:10,478] DEBUG Close called on already closed client (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-04-18 15:54:10,478] DEBUG Closing ZkClient...done (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-04-18 15:54:10,480] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkAuthFailedException: Authentication failure
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.waitForKeeperState(ZkClient.java:947)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.waitUntilConnected(ZkClient.java:924)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1231)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:157)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:131)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:79)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:61)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZk(KafkaServer.scala:329)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:187)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:39)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2017-04-18 15:54:10,482] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Following configuration is given in the JAAS file, which is passed as KAFKA_OPTS to take it as JVM parameter:-

```
  KafkaServer {
       org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
       username="admin"
       password="admin-secret"
       user_admin="admin-secret";
  };

  Client {
      org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
      username="admin"
      password="admin-secret";
  };
```

kafka broker's server.properties has following extra fields set:-

```
zookeeper.set.acl=true
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
ssl.keystore.location=path
ssl.keystore.password=anything
ssl.key.password=anything
ssl.truststore.location=path
ssl.truststore.password=anything
```

Zookeeper properties are as follows:

```
 authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestAuthenticationProvider
jaasLoginRenew=3600000
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
```

Comment: Ok you don't use SSL, I presume?

Comment: yes i do not want ssl between zookeeper and broker. but ssl is set for kafka client communication.

Comment: @M.Situation i have added the ssl configurations, i am using for kafka client and kafka broker

Comment: Ok. let me see that

Comment: @M.Situation any idea, if i am missing some configuration. My main aim is to secure zookeeper and kafka broker communication and as well secure zookeeper client to zookeeper server authentication

Comment: Can you increase the log level?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141973/discussion-between-m-situation-and-sunder).

Comment: I found the issue. Let me post it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found the issue by increasing the log level to DEBUG. Basically follow the steps below. I don't use SSL but you will integrate it without any issue.

Following are my configuration files:

**server.properties**

```
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN

authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
auto.create.topics.enable=false
broker.id=0
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

advertised.host.name=localhost
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.flush.interval.messages=30000000
log.flush.interval.ms=1800000
log.retention.minutes=30
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
delete.topic.enable=true
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
super.users=User:admin
```

**zookeeper.properties**

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=0
authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
jaasLoginRenew=3600000
```

**producer.properties**

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
compression.type=none
```

**consumer.properties**

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.id=test-consumer-group
```

Now are the most important files for making your server starting without any issue:

**zookeeper_jaas.conf**

```
Server {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret"
   user_admin="admin-secret";
};
```

**kafka_server_jaas.conf**

```
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret"
   user_admin="admin-secret";
};

Client {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret";
};
```

After doing all these configuration, on a first terminal window:

**Terminal 1 (start Zookeeper server)**

From kafka root directory

```
$ export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/usename/Documents/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/config/zookeeper_jaas.conf"
$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

**Terminal 2 (start Kafka server)**

From kafka root directory

```
$ export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/usename/Documents/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

**[BEGIN UPDATE]**

**kafka_client_jaas.conf**

```
KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin-secret";
};
```

**Terminal 3 (start Kafka consumer)**

On a client terminal, export client jaas conf file and start consumer:

```
$ export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/username/Documents/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/kafka_client_jaas.conf"
$ ./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test-topic --from-beginning --consumer.config=config/consumer.properties  --bootstrap-server=localhost:9092
```

**Terminal 4 (start Kafka producer)**

If you also want to produce, do this on another terminal window:

```
$ export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/username/Documents/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/kafka_client_jaas.conf"
$ ./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test-topic --producer.config=config/producer.properties
```

**[END UPDATE]**

Comment: Yeah!! it worked fine. Thanks a lot for ur help, i have been struggling since last 2 days

Comment: Just curious to know the real cause of failure. Was it zookeeper is expecting a Server {} configuration?

Comment: Exactly. It was the missing piece

Comment: any idea if some special configuration is required for producer and consumer's communication. I am facing 
Bootstrap broker localhost:<port> disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) for producer

Comment: Did you add `client jaas`? It's probably the missing piece in your stuff. Before producing or consuming, you need to export a `client jaas`.

Comment: Where exactly this file has to be provided. Don't you think 'kafka_server.jaas' has a Client section and exporting it in java.security.auth.login.config parameter in JVM would suffice?
I am running producer in the terminal 2 in your answer, so which already has config file imported.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but i felt from producer config that it is connecting to kafka broker and not zookeeper directly. So in that case why would producer need that config file?

Comment: Producers/consumers need to be authenticated before trying  to produce/consume. The client jaas is used for this purpose. Let me update my post and you will see what I mean

Comment: You have a typo in your zookeeper_jaas.conf file. Missing a semicolon at the end of user_admin="admin-secret";

Comment: typo kafka_server.jaas -> kafka_server_jaas.conf

Comment: Thanks for the note. Updated

Comment: I did followed this but I am getting one error as: ERROR SASL authentication failed using login context 'Client' with exception: {} (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Error in authenticating with a Zookeeper Quorum member: the quorum member's saslToken is null.

Any help?

Comment: @M.Situation This configuration you specified is for zookeeper in kafka package, what should be the config for standalone zookeeper?

Comment: I think it needs some updates, I have tried this and I faced error in that as zookeeper does not support - PlainLoginModule, it uses DigestLoginModule. so the changes would be  to replace "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required" by "org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required" at zookeeper_jaas.conf and Client section of kafka_server_jaas.conf

Answer (score 13):

You need to create a JAAS config file for Zookeeper and make it use it.

Create a file JAAS config file for Zookeeper with a content like this:

```
Server {
    org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
    user_admin="admin-secret";
};
```

Where user (admin) and password (admin-secret) must match with username and password that you have in Client section of Kafka JAAS config file.

To make Zookeeper use the JAAS config file, pass the following JVM flag to Zookeeper pointing to the file created before.

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/server/jaas/file.conf"
```

If you are using Zookeeper included with Kafka package you can launch Zookeeper like this, assuming that your Zookeeper JAAS config file is located in ./config/zookeeper_jaas.conf

```
EXTRA_ARGS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./config/zookeeper_jaas.conf ./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh ./config/zookeeper.properties
```

Comment: As of November 2019 this is the most current and concise answer!