# How to resolve a zookeeper authentication failure when using Kafka with Kerberos

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kerberos

I am trying to use SASL between my kafka broker and zookeeper. When I start the kafka server

```
KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/kafka/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf" \
    ./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties
```

I get the following error:

```
INFO TGT refresh thread started. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
DEBUG Client principal is "kafkabroker1/kafka.eigenroute.com@EIGENROUTE.COM". (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
DEBUG Server principal is "krbtgt/EIGENROUTE.COM@EIGENROUTE.COM". (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
INFO TGT valid starting at:        Sat Dec 16 00:32:52 EST 2017 (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
INFO TGT expires:                  Sat Dec 16 10:32:52 EST 2017 (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
INFO TGT refresh sleeping until: Sat Dec 16 08:55:41 EST 2017 (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
INFO Opening socket connection to server devel-2.sjml.com/173.243.38.81:2181. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
DEBUG Closing ZkClient... (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
DEBUG Closing ZooKeeper connected to zookeeper.eigenroute.com:2181 (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection)
DEBUG Closing session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
DEBUG Closing client for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 6004ms for sessionid 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
DEBUG An exception was thrown while closing send thread for session 0x0 : Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 6004ms for sessionid 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
DEBUG Ignoring exception during shutdown input (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO)
java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected
```

My questions are: what is going on? And how to do I fix this?

Below are my configuration files. The first is `server.properties`:

```
# server.properties
broker.id=0
delete.topic.enable=true

listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://kafka.eigenroute.com:9092
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=GSSAPI
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=GSSAPI
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafkabroker1
inter.broker.listener.name=SASL_PLAINTEXT

authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
super.users=User:kafkabroker1

...

zookeeper.connect=zookeeper.eigenroute.com:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

Here is `kafka_server_jaas.conf`

```
KafkaServer {
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
        refreshKrb5Config=true
        useKeyTab=true
        storeKey=true
        keyTab="/home/kafka/keytabs/kafka_broker1.keytab"
        principal="kafkabroker1/kafka.eigenroute.com@EIGENROUTE.COM";
};

Client {
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
        useTicketCache=true
        refreshKrb5Config=true
        useKeyTab=true
        storeKey=true
        keyTab="/home/kafka/keytabs/kafka_broker1.keytab"
        principal="kafkabroker1/kafka.eigenroute.com@EIGENROUTE.COM";
};
```

This is the zookeeper file in `/etc/init.d`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ZOOCFGDIR="/etc/zookeeper/conf/"
export SERVER_JVMFLAGS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/zookeeper/conf/zookeeper.jaas -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf"
echo "$@"
/usr/share/java/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/zkServer.sh $@ /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
```

Here is my zookeeper configuration file `zoo.cfg`:

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
jaasLoginRenew=3600000
```

I have enabled `useTicketCache=true` in the zookeeper.jaas file (does it belong there?):

```
Server {
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
        useTicketCache=true
        refreshKrb5Config=true
        useKeyTab=true
        keyTab="/home/kafka/keytabs/zookeeper.keytab"
        storeKey=true
        principal="zookeeper/zookeeper.eigenroute.com@EIGENROUTE.COM";
};
```

Finally, the keytab files are all readable:

```
$ ll /home/kafka/keytabs/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  2 sjamal sjamal 4096 Dec 12 11:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 kafka  kafka  4096 Dec 12 11:57 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    366 Dec 12 11:24 kafka_broker1.keytab
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    426 Dec 12 11:31 testkafkaconsumer1.keytab
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    426 Dec 12 11:31 testkafkaproducer1.keytab
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    370 Dec 12 11:32 zookeeper.keytab
```

I have consulted the following resources:

- [apache-kafka-security-authorization-authentication-encryption](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-security-authorization-authentication-encryption/). 
  [Kafka SASL zookeeper authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469962/kafka-sasl-zookeeper-authentication) (this says to add the `zookeeper.set.acl=true` to server.properties, but this has no effect on the issue I am experiencing)
- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration (the official documentation, which could use improvement in some areas)
- https://coheigea.blogspot.ca/2017/05/securing-apache-kafka-with-kerberos.html (a set of instructions that I initially started following)

Can someone suggest what the problem might be, and how to fix this? Thanks!

UPDATE: I ran `netstat -tulnp | grep 2181` and `ps aux | grep zookeeper`, the output below shows that Zookeeper is running and listening on port 2181:

```
root@devel-2:~# netstat -tulnp | grep 2181
tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN      3366/java
root@devel-2:~# ps aux | grep zookeeper
root      3366  0.0  0.6 3474796 26000 ?       Sl   Dec16   1:43 java -Dzookeeper.log.dir=. -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE -cp /usr/share/java/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../build/classes:/usr/share/java/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.10.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/etc/zookeeper/conf/: -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/zookeeper/conf/log4j.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/zookeeper/conf/zookeeper.jaas -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/zookeeper/conf/jaas.conf -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
```

UPDATE: The software versions are:

- Kerberos 5 version 1.12.1
- Zookeeper 3.4.10
- Kafka 0.11.0.0

UPDATE: Below is the content of my `/etc/krb5.conf` file:

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = EIGENROUTE.COM

# The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.
        krb4_config = /etc/krb.conf
        krb4_realms = /etc/krb.realms
        kdc_timesync = 1
        ccache_type = 4
        forwardable = true
        proxiable = true
# The following libdefaults parameters are only for Heimdal Kerberos.
        v4_instance_resolve = false
        v4_name_convert = {
                host = {
                        rcmd = host
                        ftp = ftp
                }
                plain = {
                        something = something-else
                }
        }
        fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

[realms]
        EIGENROUTE.COM = {
                kdc = krb.eigenroute.com
                admin_server = krb.eigenroute.com
                default_domain = eigenroute.com
        }
        ATHENA.MIT.EDU = {
                kdc = kerberos.mit.edu:88
                kdc = kerberos-1.mit.edu:88
                kdc = kerberos-2.mit.edu:88
                admin_server = kerberos.mit.edu
                default_domain = mit.edu
        }
        MEDIA-LAB.MIT.EDU = {
                kdc = kerberos.media.mit.edu
                admin_server = kerberos.media.mit.edu
        }
        ZONE.MIT.EDU = {
                kdc = casio.mit.edu
                kdc = seiko.mit.edu
                admin_server = casio.mit.edu
        }
        MOOF.MIT.EDU = {
                kdc = three-headed-dogcow.mit.edu:88
                kdc = three-headed-dogcow-1.mit.edu:88
                admin_server = three-headed-dogcow.mit.edu
        }
        CSAIL.MIT.EDU = {
                kdc = kerberos-1.csail.mit.edu
                kdc = kerberos-2.csail.mit.edu
                admin_server = kerberos.csail.mit.edu
                default_domain = csail.mit.edu
                krb524_server = krb524.csail.mit.edu
        }
        IHTFP.ORG = {
                kdc = kerberos.ihtfp.org
                admin_server = kerberos.ihtfp.org
        }
        GNU.ORG = {
                kdc = kerberos.gnu.org
                kdc = kerberos-2.gnu.org
                kdc = kerberos-3.gnu.org
                admin_server = kerberos.gnu.org
        }
        1TS.ORG = {
                kdc = kerberos.1ts.org
                admin_server = kerberos.1ts.org
        }
        GRATUITOUS.ORG = {
                kdc = kerberos.gratuitous.org
                admin_server = kerberos.gratuitous.org
        }
        DOOMCOM.ORG = {
                kdc = kerberos.doomcom.org
                admin_server = kerberos.doomcom.org
        }
        ANDREW.CMU.EDU = {
                kdc = kerberos.andrew.cmu.edu
                kdc = kerberos2.andrew.cmu.edu
                kdc = kerberos3.andrew.cmu.edu
                admin_server = kerberos.andrew.cmu.edu
                default_domain = andrew.cmu.edu
        }
        CS.CMU.EDU = {
                kdc = kerberos.cs.cmu.edu
                kdc = kerberos-2.srv.cs.cmu.edu
                admin_server = kerberos.cs.cmu.edu
        }
        DEMENTIA.ORG = {
                kdc = kerberos.dementix.org
                kdc = kerberos2.dementix.org
                admin_server = kerberos.dementix.org
        }
        stanford.edu = {
                kdc = krb5auth1.stanford.edu
                kdc = krb5auth2.stanford.edu
                kdc = krb5auth3.stanford.edu
                master_kdc = krb5auth1.stanford.edu
                admin_server = krb5-admin.stanford.edu
                default_domain = stanford.edu
        }
        UTORONTO.CA = {
                kdc = kerberos1.utoronto.ca
                kdc = kerberos2.utoronto.ca
                kdc = kerberos3.utoronto.ca
                admin_server = kerberos1.utoronto.ca
                default_domain = utoronto.ca
        }

[domain_realm]
        .mit.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
        mit.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
        .media.mit.edu = MEDIA-LAB.MIT.EDU
        media.mit.edu = MEDIA-LAB.MIT.EDU
        .csail.mit.edu = CSAIL.MIT.EDU
        csail.mit.edu = CSAIL.MIT.EDU
        .whoi.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
        whoi.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
        .stanford.edu = stanford.edu
        .slac.stanford.edu = SLAC.STANFORD.EDU
        .toronto.edu = UTORONTO.CA
        .utoronto.ca = UTORONTO.CA
        .eigenroute.com = EIGENROUTE.COM
        eigenroute.com = EIGENROUTE.COM

[login]
        krb4_convert = true
        krb4_get_tickets = false
[logging]
       kdc = FILE:/var/log/kerberos/krb5kdc.log
  admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kerberos/kadmin.log
   default = FILE:/var/log/kerberos/krb5lib.log
```

Comment: Let's see your /etc/krb5.conf

Comment: @T-Heron: I have edited the question to include the `/etc/krb5.conf` file contents, thanks. I used the default and then modified the file according to the instructions here: `https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/install_kdc.html#install-and-configure-the-master-kdc`

Comment: This error seems pertinent: *INFO Opening socket connection to server devel-2.sjml.com/173.243.38.81:2181. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
DEBUG Closing ZkClient... (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)*.   Something is being instructed to open a connection to server devel-2.sjml.com/173.243.38.81:2181 while the Kerberos SPN is kafkabroker1/kafka.eigenroute.com@EIGENROUTE.COM.  A mismatch there.  Nothing about sjml.com is mentioned in any config file.  Do you have an SPN for it?  You should, if its a Kerberos-protecoted service

Comment: @T-Heron: My `/etc/hosts` file on the Kerberos server (which is on the same server as Zookeeper, for now) contains the following line: `173.243.38.81 devel-2.sjml.com  devel-2`, which is where I'm sure where the `sjml.com` comes from. Should I change this line? I looked at some of the Zookeeper source and didn't see a way to override this.

Comment: I didn't solve this, and actually had trouble reproducing the exact error, but I think that the problem is related to what @T-Heron suggested. For those running into similar problems, I did have some success in configuring SASL with ZooKeeper - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934580/zookeeper-sasl-checksum-failed

Comment: Voted to close as even the asker indicates the exact error cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Somehow my close vote dissappeared, again voted to close as this is about kafka 0.11 which is also a VERY old version and as such the issue is unlikely to still be relevant and reproducible in any recent version.