# How to setup SASL authentication for Zookeeper

Tags: authentication, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, sasl

I have successfully setup SASL PLAIN and PLAINTEXT security for Kafka brokers, in a sense that clients cannot consume or produce successfully without providing `kafka_client_jaas.conf` with valid username and password credentials, due to authentication failure.

However, I cannot do the same for Zookeeper, so that for example `kafka_topics.sh` successfully connects to Zookeeper, without having `KAFKA_OPTS` setting `java.security.auth.login.config` that would point to any `jaas.conf` file. I imagined it would have to point to same `kafka_client_jaas.conf` as console consumers and producers, since there is a Client section defined for authentication to Zookeeper. I added following three lines to `zookeeper.properties` file (I don't know what is the third line used for):

```
authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
jaasLoginRenew=3600000
```

I created `zookeeper_jaas.conf` (defining Server section) and started Zookeeper with `KAFKA_OPTS` pointing to it, and added Client section to `kafka_server_jaas.conf` so that brokers authenticate properly to Zookeeper, pretty much as described here:

[Kafka SASL zookeeper authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469962/kafka-sasl-zookeeper-authentication)

but I cannot provoke authentication failure when running `kafka_topics.sh`, as already mentioned. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: If you provide `KAFKA_OPTS` along with the `kafka-topics`, then it authenticates... I'm not understanding the problem

Comment: The problem is that it authenticates somehow also when I unset KAFKA_OPTS in the shell from where I run kafka-topics.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem here. I've configured Zookeeper's Server to Server authentication with SASL and works, but Client to Server, isn't. Any Zookeeper client can connect to the cluster.