# Kafka Server not starting up. Gives: Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to run Junit tests for my application, and trying to start the Kafka services as part of my tests.
But, I am getting the `NullPointerException` after the zookeeper is started and the Kafka server ends abruptly.

> Kafka Client Version: 2.4.1

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(KafkaConfig.HostNameProp(), "localhost");
    props.setProperty(KafkaConfig.PortProp(), String.valueOf(KAFKA_BROKER_PORT));
    props.setProperty(KafkaConfig.BrokerIdProp(), String.valueOf(KAFKA_BROKER_ID));
    props.setProperty(KafkaConfig.LogDirProp(), Environment.getLogsDir());
    props.setProperty(KafkaConfig.LogDirProp(), System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/kafka-logs");
    props.setProperty("enable.zookeeper", "false");
    props.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
    props.setProperty("zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms", "10000");
    props.setProperty("offsets.topic.replication.factor", "1");
    props.setProperty("log.flush.interval.messages", "1");
    props.setProperty(KafkaConfig.GroupMaxSessionTimeoutMsProp(), "100000");

    // flush every message.
    props.setProperty("log.flush.interval", "1");

    // flush every 1ms
    props.setProperty("log.default.flush.scheduler.interval.ms", "1");
    props.setProperty("log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms", "1");


    kafkaServerStartable = KafkaServerStartable.fromProps(props);


    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (kafkaServerStartable != null) {
                kafkaServerStartable.shutdown();
            }
        };

      });
    System.setProperty("zookeeper.sasl.clientconfig", "test");
    System.setProperty("zookeeper.sasl.client", "false");
    kafkaServerStartable.startup();
```

Any help/leads will be helpful. Thanks!

StackTrace/Logs:

```
2021-05-12 11:05:29,944 INFO [kafka.server.KafkaServer][main] [] starting
2021-05-12 11:05:29,948 INFO [kafka.server.KafkaServer][main] [] Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2181
2021-05-12 11:05:30,024 INFO [kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient][main] [] [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Initializing a new session to localhost:2181.
2021-05-12 11:05:30,027 INFO [org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper][main] [] Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@29bc4bf4
2021-05-12 11:05:30,027 INFO [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket][main] [] jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes
2021-05-12 11:05:30,028 INFO [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn][main] [] zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=
2021-05-12 11:05:30,034 INFO [kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient][main] [] [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected.
2021-05-12 11:05:30,035 INFO [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn][main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] [] Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2021-05-12 11:05:30,036 INFO [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn][main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] [] Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:59560, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2021-05-12 11:05:30,037 ERROR [org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperSaslServer][NIOServerCxnFactory.SelectorThread-0] [] server principal name/hostname determination error: 
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.util.SecurityUtils.createSaslServer(SecurityUtils.java:174)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperSaslServer.createSaslServer(ZooKeeperSaslServer.java:44)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperSaslServer.<init>(ZooKeeperSaslServer.java:38)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.<init>(NIOServerCnxn.java:104)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.createConnection(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:848)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory$SelectorThread.processAcceptedConnections(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:479)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory$SelectorThread.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:392)
2021-05-12 11:05:30,056 INFO [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn][main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] [] Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x10143dd4de40008, negotiated timeout = 6000
2021-05-12 11:05:30,065 INFO [kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient][main] [] [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected.
2021-05-12 11:05:30,478 ERROR [kafka.server.KafkaServer][main] [] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.ResolvedRecursiveType.equals(ResolvedRecursiveType.java:103)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings$AsKey.equals(TypeBindings.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:947)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.LRUMap.get(LRUMap.java:68)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1211)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:1384)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1154)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._resolveSuperInterfaces(TypeFactory.java:1298)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1243)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:1384)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1154)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._resolveSuperInterfaces(TypeFactory.java:1298)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1243)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:1384)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1154)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:1380)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1154)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._resolveSuperInterfaces(TypeFactory.java:1298)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1243)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:1384)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1154)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._resolveSuperInterfaces(TypeFactory.java:1298)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1243)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:1384)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1154)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._resolveSuperInterfaces(TypeFactory.java:1298)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1243)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:1384)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1154)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._resolveSuperInterfaces(TypeFactory.java:1298)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1243)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:1384)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1154)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._resolveSuperInterfaces(TypeFactory.java:1298)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1243)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromParamType(TypeFactory.java:1384)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1154)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(TypeFactory.java:622)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveType(AnnotatedClass.java:228)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedConstructor.getParameterType(AnnotatedConstructor.java:104)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedWithParams.getParameter(AnnotatedWithParams.java:105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addCreators(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:449)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:303)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getJsonValueMethod(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:172)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findJsonValueMethod(BasicBeanDescription.java:224)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerByAnnotations(BasicSerializerFactory.java:350)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.buildMapSerializer(BasicSerializerFactory.java:763)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.buildContainerSerializer(BasicSerializerFactory.java:572)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory._createSerializer2(BeanSerializerFactory.java:190)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1272)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1222)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:499)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:697)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:270)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3672)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(ObjectMapper.java:3072)
    at kafka.utils.Json$.encodeAsBytes(Json.scala:115)
    at kafka.zk.ClusterIdZNode$.toJson(ZkData.scala:709)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createOrGetClusterId(KafkaZkClient.scala:1524)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer$$anonfun$getOrGenerateClusterId$1.apply(KafkaServer.scala:404)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer$$anonfun$getOrGenerateClusterId$1.apply(KafkaServer.scala:404)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.getOrGenerateClusterId(KafkaServer.scala:404)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:210)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
```

Tried debugging the class, found that the code throws the exception when it is trying to get the cluster id of the already **connected** (as per the logs) Zookeeper.

Comment: Please show your code and your broker settings

Comment: @OneCricketeer Edited the question with the code used to start the Kafka.

Comment: Have you tried using the spring-kafka-test embedded broker? Or other kafka-junit projects found on Github? Or testcontainers?

Comment: I feel like you've not setup SASL correctly, but you've told Zookeeper some properties about it (the error is related to SASL configuration).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469962/kafka-sasl-zookeeper-authentication And you've also got that `zookeeper.enabled=false` on the broker, which does nothing for Kafka 2.4