# Bypass kafka authorization for port 9092 (plaintext)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I want to add authentication and authorization for my confluent kafka running with docker. This should only happen on port 9093, 9092 should work as before because the port is blocked for external clients by ip table rules. Therefore I used following config:

=> 9093 SASL_SSL
=> 9092 PLAINTEXT

Here is a part of my config:
**Kafka container environment variables**

```
  - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://my.host.ip:9092,SASL_SSL://my.host.ip:9093
  - KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND=false
  - KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH=required
  - KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=SASL_SSL
  - KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=PLAIN
  - KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS=PLAIN
  - KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
  - KAFKA_SUPER_USERS="User:admin"
  - KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/secrets
```

**Zookeeper container environment variables**

```
  - ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;my.host.ip:2888:3888
  - ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID=1
  - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
  - ZOOKEEPER_STANDALONE_ENABLED=false
  - ZOOKEEPER_DATA_DIR=/kafka/data
  - ZOOKEEPER_AUTH_PROVIDER_SASL=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
  - KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/secrets/zookeeper_jaas.conf
```

As I only want to configure the authentication mechanism for the SASL_SSL listener I use following jaas config as described here: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/index.html#recommended-broker-jaas-configuration.

**kafka_jaas.config**

```
KafkaServer {
listener.name.sasl_ssl.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin"
  user_admin="admin"
};

Client {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
 username="admin"
 password="admin";
};
```

**zookeeper_jaas.config**

```
Server {
       org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
       user_admin="admin";
};
```

When I run kafka i get the following error:

```
[main-SendThread(s415vm2140.detss.corpintra.net:2181)] WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - SASL configuration failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Zookeeper client cannot authenticate using the 'Client' section of the supplied JAAS configuration: '/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka_jaas.conf' because of a RuntimeException: java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    Line 2: expected [controlFlag] Will continue connection to Zookeeper server without SASL authentication, if Zookeeper server allows it.
```

How can I achieve that a client does not need to authentication when connecting to port 9092?

Comment: That "error" is a **warning** from the Zookeeper client, nothing to do with Kafka client SSL/SASL connections. You should show your Zookeeper settings as well

Answer (score 0):

Read more here:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/zk-security.html

You set Zookeeper to working with digest, you set client with Plain,
On kafka_jaas

```
KafkaServer {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
     username="admin"
      password="admin"
      user_admin="admin";
};

Client {
       org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
       username="admin"
       password="admin";
};
```

And in zookeeper_jaas

```
Server {
   org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
       username="admin"
       password="admin"
       user_admin="admin";
};
```

P.s.
1.`listener.name.sasl_ssl.plain.sasl.jaas.config=` in your KafkaServer is not correct

2. You are missing " ;  "

Here you also have an example of configuration with Plain

[Kafka SASL zookeeper authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469962/kafka-sasl-zookeeper-authentication)